# Java xml saver optimization

Tags: java, xml

I have a colection of objects organised in trees that i want to save as a XML file, but i want to do this as optimally as i can. I use somehing like this (see the code) to do it, but i would appeciate if someone could tell me a better way of doing it :

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);


    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);


    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);


    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);


    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);


    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);


    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
    staff.appendChild(salary);


    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));


    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shot answer is: use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

In case of using it, you can put annotation such as @XmlElement on your fields and classes to serialize/deserialize them to XML seamlessly. And it will handle all the recursion in your tree without any problems.

Comment: +1 for JAXB, also note that JAXB has default rules for converting Java objects to XML so you only need to add annotations where you wish to specify non-default mappings:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: @Funtik - JAXB is really simple to use as well:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Comment: @Blaise Doughan +1 for the blog-post. My opinion is based on my previous bad experience with JAXB a couple of years ago. At that time I found Simple to be simpler and more efficient framework for XML transformations.

Comment: I don't really need simple, coding is not an issue; what i need is to use as little memory as possible because it's just a small part of a bigger project.